# Android app cannot switch layout

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I was working on a new android application and there is some kind of error. I cannot switch the activity. My first activity is named MainActivity and my second activity is named Themes. The button name is themes_button.
Here's the code i used.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) { 

       case R.id.themes_button:
         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Themes.class));
         break;

       default:
         break;

      }
 }
```

Comment: Did you set Onclick for themes_button ?

Comment: No i have not. All my other buttons work fine without that.

Comment: or add android:onClick="onClick" to xml layout ?

Comment: i added that and now the app crashes when i click the button

Comment: have you added `yourButton.setOnClickListner(this);` in your `onCreate()` ??

Comment: Post logcat. Is `Themes` listed as an `Activity` in the manifest?

Answer (score 2):

Please write android:onClick="onClick" and give            android:id="@+id/themes_button in xml file then it works properly.

You may use it :

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

In activity class :

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

   Button bt ;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1)

    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bt:
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Themes.class));
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}
```